# Changing viewcontroller and tasks in background state in iOS apps

Tags: ios, audio, uiviewcontroller, background

I want to change the root `viewcontroller` of the application, after the end of playing an audio. Also I want to play another audio.

Is this possible to handle in the background state?

Comment: You should show some attempts at code you have tried, as this question is very broad right now

Comment: Your question is lacking some of the required information. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? Thanks!

Comment: I have set a listener to know the end of audio play. On executing the listener, i'm invoking a method -loadDetailView. For that i'm pushing the viewController to a new one named DetailViewController. On this viewDidLoad im playing another audio. It's working okay for me, i'm not sure if this is correct approach. But on background case, i'm able to handle the case, only after coming to forground. Since the second audio  should also play immediately after the end of playing the first audio,i'm not able to handle the case properly. Please help

Comment: broke up paragraphs and improved grammar.